# remove part of string in few rows r

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have datafarme like this

```
dummy_data <- structure(list(Date = c("24/06/2002", "24/06/2002", "01/07/2002", 
                                     "01/07/2002", "08/07/2002", 
                                     "08/07/2002","15/07/2002","17/07/2002", 
                                     "22/07/2002", "22/07/2002", "29/07/2002"), 
                             Temp_id= c("ABC", "M567", "M567", "M567", "XYZ", "XYZ", 
                                "T300/500,XYZ", "T300/390,XYZ", "0000,M300", "1234,M678", "ABC")), class = 
                           "data.frame", 
                        row.names = c(NA, 
                                      -11L))
```

In some of the rows in column "temp_id" there is an additional text.

How can I remove the part before ',' and leave the rest of the string in the column?

```
Required output <-  dummy_data <- structure(list(Date = c("24/06/2002", "24/06/2002", "01/07/2002",   "01/07/2002", "08/07/2002", "08/07/2002","15/07/2002","17/07/2002", 
                                         "22/07/2002", "22/07/2002", "29/07/2002"), 
                                 Temp_id= c("ABC", "M567", "M567", "M567", "XYZ", "XYZ", 
                                    "XYZ", "XYZ", "M300", "M678", "ABC")), class=  "data.frame",  row.names = c(NA,  -11L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your colum `Temp_id`:

```
Temp_id= c("ABC", "M567", "M567", "M567", "XYZ", "XYZ", 
           "T300/500,XYZ", "T300/390,XYZ", "0000,M300", "1234,M678", "ABC"))
```

Which:

```
 [1] "ABC"          "M567"         "M567"         "M567"         "XYZ"          "XYZ"          "T300/500,XYZ"
 [8] "T300/390,XYZ" "0000,M300"    "1234,M678"    "ABC"
```

An easy way is using `gsub` function which replaces the regex pattern you indicate with other expression. In this case we are indicating that everying from the beggining of the line to the first comma - ^.*, -  is replaced with nothing - '' .

```
gsub('^.*,','',Temp_id)

[1] "ABC"  "M567" "M567" "M567" "XYZ"  "XYZ"  "XYZ"  "XYZ"  "M300" "M678" "ABC"
```

In case you don't understand the regex symbols:

> ^ -> beginning of line,   . -> every character ,   * -> repeat previous ' . '
> until next symbol matches,   , -> stop in comma

Applying to the dataframe:

```
dummy_data$Temp_id = gsub('^.*,','',dummy_data$Temp_id)

> dummy_data
         Date Temp_id
1  24/06/2002     ABC
2  24/06/2002    M567
3  01/07/2002    M567
4  01/07/2002    M567
5  08/07/2002     XYZ
6  08/07/2002     XYZ
7  15/07/2002     XYZ
8  17/07/2002     XYZ
9  22/07/2002    M300
10 22/07/2002    M678
11 29/07/2002     ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` and `stringr`...

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


dummy_data |> 
  mutate(Temp_id = case_when(str_detect(Temp_id, ",") ~ str_extract(Temp_id, "(?<=,).*$"),
                             TRUE ~ Temp_id))
#or using `ifelse()`

dummy_data |> 
  mutate(Temp_id = ifelse(str_detect(Temp_id, ","),
                          str_extract(Temp_id, "(?<=,).*$"),
                          Temp_id))

#>          Date Temp_id
#> 1  24/06/2002     ABC
#> 2  24/06/2002    M567
#> 3  01/07/2002    M567
#> 4  01/07/2002    M567
#> 5  08/07/2002     XYZ
#> 6  08/07/2002     XYZ
#> 7  15/07/2002     XYZ
#> 8  17/07/2002     XYZ
#> 9  22/07/2002    M300
#> 10 22/07/2002    M678
#> 11 29/07/2002     ABC
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This too works:

```
lirary(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dummy_data %>% 
  mutate(Temp_id = str_extract(Temp_id, "[^,]+$"))
         Date Temp_id
1  24/06/2002     ABC
2  24/06/2002    M567
3  01/07/2002    M567
4  01/07/2002    M567
5  08/07/2002     XYZ
6  08/07/2002     XYZ
7  15/07/2002     XYZ
8  17/07/2002     XYZ
9  22/07/2002    M300
10 22/07/2002    M678
11 29/07/2002     ABC
```

Here `[^,]+$` matches any sequence of characters that are **not** (`^`) a comma up until the end (`$`) of the string, thus effectively removing any part before the comma (including the comma itself) if present.

Alternatively, we can do this in `base R`like so:

```
sub(".*?([^,]+)$", "\\1", dummy_data$Temp_id)
```

where `.*?` is a 'lazy' match of anything that is prior to any sequence of characters that are **not** (`^`) a comma up until the end (`$`) of the string and where `\\1` is a backreference that refers back to that sequence captured by `(...)`